# Nested or flattened classes structure?

Tags: python, oop

I would like to implement a representation of a physical system and its hierarchy into a classes structure. Many examples found on the internet suggest this method:

```
sport = Sport()
soccer = sport.GetSoccer()
ball = soccer.GetBall()
ball.Kick()
```

However, I feel that the following would be much easier to use:

```
sport = Sport()
sport.soccer.ball.Kick()
```

Is there any standards or conventions for choosing the former over the latter?

**EDIT**

Regarding the answers of [BrianO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2427263/briano) and [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin), I should provide another example than soccer and sport which is not representative of my real needs.

The real context is an embedded device *i.e.* [ASIMO](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASIMO), interfaced through an API written in C. This API is composed of thousands of functions not hierarchically organized.

My goal is to implement a kind of ORM (I don't know the proper term for this), that bring a hierarchical access of these functions.

In other words, if I want to move the midddle finger of the left arm of the robot, I will probably call an obscure function with obscure parameters like this:

```
_dll.asimo_arm_left_hand_move_finger(2, 1, 3, 2, 4)
```

A better approach is to provide an OOP solution with something like:

```
asimo.arms.left.hand.middleFinger.join[1].ApplyTorque(2) # [nNm]
```

This approach would help the users to communicate with the robot in an interactive console with all the benefits provided by the auto-completion.

Note that the `asimo` think is just an example; i am not working with a robot.

Comment: I personally think the latter is better. However, how you implement it matters. You shouldn't define `soccer` as a class within `Sport`, but assigning the class `Soccer` as an attribute of `Sport` is fine.

Comment: @sweeneyrod, Please, do not give your personnal thinking here (this question may be closed on personal opinions). I would prefer an answer based on existing standards or conventions.

Comment: There is nothing mysterious with this task, just if you want to use `sport.GetSoccer()` and `soccer.GetBall()` methods later you better to use the former approach in otherwise, the last approach is the pythonic way to go with this task!

Comment: @Kasramvd Well I imagine both approach would be possible in that case especially if we are dealing with singletons.

Comment: Your first example can be written `Sport().GetSoccer().GetBall().Kick()` which, apart from the semantics of this (what does this statement *mean*?) I think is preferable. But you have what appears to be a constructor `Sport`, two accessors `GetSoccer` and `GetBall`, and an imperative `Kick`. You have to decide what you want this to do before you can choose an optimal expression. Should `Sport` be `GetSport`? And should some of those methods have parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully, there are no standards or conventions that would prefer either, because each one is a mishmash of sports, things used in sports, and actions performed on such things. Such types of entities don't form an "is-a" hierarchy. A soccer ball is not a kind of soccer; a kick is not a kind of ball. Is `Kick` supposed to be a class?! That's nutty/wrong. Common sense should tell you it's a method -- of *something*, though probably not of a ball (more plausibly, a method of a `Player` class, applied to a `Ball` argument).

Think this through more, keeping in mind that inheritance (is-a, inclusion) and containment (has-a, membership) are distinct though complementary modelling tools.

#### Added after your edit:

Thanks for explaining more of your actual concerns. You have an interesting and challenging problem, in two parts, only the first of which you're asking about here: (*) how to properly model your hierarchy of gizmos, their subsystems, subassemblies of those, and parts thereof; and (**) how to set up a correspondence between that model and the flat API of thousands of functions.

I like your thinking: an interactive console with autocompletion gives a much better UX when there's intuitively correct hierarchy of objects, compared to an API of 1000+ randomly organized functions. (Ideally, a dynamic GUI with a velocity-sensitive touchscreen... but maybe next year for that.)

Your users will wind up entering dotted expressions like `this.that.type_of_that.part_of_that.sub_part.left_corner.apply_force(3500)`. Across the dots, the relationship will sometimes be "is-a" (subclass), and other times "has-a" (is an attribute of). Your problem is clearly too big, and perhaps proprietary, for you to post in its full gory detail, so it's difficult to offer more pointed advice.

#### Speculative vague generalities:

In any case, you'll have choices to make. Your representation should be influenced though not determined by the API you're targeting: you don't want to make make things harder for yourself than they already are.

Suppose your devices are Cars, standard ones with 4 wheels, 4 lamps, 2 axes of symmetry, an engine, etc. If the API provides separate functions that operate on the front wheels and on the rear ones, then you might want the `wheels` attribute of a `Car` object to be a namedtuple with fields `front` and `rear`, each of which is in turn a WheelPair object, with attributes (members) `left` and `right`, which are Wheel objects. If `car` is a Car object, then `car.wheels.front.left` would be a Wheel, which might have a `pressurePSI` property, a float value (and other properties for different units the API makes available).

If, however, the API has functions which act on all wheels and others which act on just one, only, then the previous representation could be awkward, and you might prefer a flatter one -- say, a namedtuple with fields `'left_front, right_front, left_back, right_back'`, each of whose elements is a Wheel. That would let you access each wheel by a human-friendly name as well as by index number, while also allowing you to iterate over the 4-tuple of wheels.

Although the previous example isn't exactly from your problem domain, it's likely you'll confront similar decisions. Recommended PSI *does* often differ for front and rear wheels and an extensive API for cars might reflect that; but if it doesn't, you don't have to either. Don't be more nested than the problem requires!

Comment: That's pretty much what I was trying to say, but you thought it through properly. Well done

Comment: Thanks. I offered my response as a potential "correct answer" because the question shows some fundamental confusion. Without knowing the universe of possibilities, there's no precise "proper way to do this". For example: What is, and what isn't, a "Sport"? -- not a universal definition, just "for the sake of discussion". Do they they all have "balls", and then, just one? players? teams? leagues? seasons? circuits? Absent that info, I wouldn't write one line of code. And in any case I wouldn't write any of the lines exhibited.

(Enjoyable composer, too, Borodin is.)